# How to get VC# to rebuild auto-generated .cs files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I imagine this question has been asked and answered, but I cannot find it.

I wanted to make a simple GUI to interface to a windows 7 command. I usually use Wx, but since this was to be a windows-only thing, I decided to see if I could whip it out real fast using Visual C# 2010 Express, which I had never used before.

Things started off just great. I created a form, put a few buttons and text boxes and such on it, and hit Debug. It came up and ran just like that. No muss, no fuss. So I then designed the form just the way I wanted it, renamed the controls from "Button1" and so forth to meaningful names. But now it's a mess. By clicking around, I discovered that VC# had auto-generated two files called Form1.cs and Form1.Designer.cs. The later contains the bindings between functions and the events generated from user-clicks etc., and the former contains no-op code for those functions, for me to complete.

Problem is, the names are all still the original "Button1" and so forth, not the new ones, and the new controls I added after running the first time do not appear at all.

I want it to regenerate all that stuff afresh from the finished form. How to?

Comment: That was Lesson #1, design first, program later.  Restore your code from source control, back to the version before you started hacking it (probably Lession #2).  Right-click a name like Form1, Refactor + Rename.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for the lessons. I have always been keen to learn, ever since my first programming job in 1971, and for the three decades during which I was a professional programmer. Of course this little project is not under source control. I am retired, and it is just something I wanted to crank out in a jiffy. Is there a way to do what I want? Or must I either start over or edit those two files by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *probably* don't have an actual problem, *unless* you edited something within `Form1.Designer.cs`. Provided you left that file alone, things should just work.

Whenever you double-click on a button, or use the events interface to create event handlers, the handlers are created with the following pattern:

```
ObjectName_EventName()
```

So, for example:

```
Button1_Click()
```

If you later change the name of Button1, the event handler's name is not changed, too. But it is still attached to the proper event, again - assuming you did not edit anything in Form1.Designer.cs

If you look (but don't touch!) inside Form1.Designer.cs, you will probably find something similar to:

```
MyNewButtonName.Click += Button1_Click;
```

(I don't recall the exact syntax the editor uses for wiring up event handlers; the principle is you should see your *new* button name being attached to the *old* handler name)

Comment: I have not touched the auto-generated files. I was hoping to get VC# to start over from scratch, using the new and improved names. Perhaps if I exported the form (how?) and started a new project using the form?

Comment: Touching the generated files shouldn't help you, they're project outputs.  That would actually cause you issues.  For any given generated file the build mechanism looks at the source file and compares it with the outputs.  If the outputs are newer (e.g. the one you just "touched") then the build believes it doesn't need to compile the source.

Comment: @Peter Ah ha. I did touch one of the files by mistake, but I control-z'd it away.

Comment: @Andrew There are entries in Form1.Designer.cs for the new controls, but they are not bound to event-handlers. Only the old controls are bound to functions, using the old names.

Comment: @JiveDadson Ahhh... so you have created new controls. That's fine, too; just use the new ones and their new handlers instead. Although it might be worth it to just wipe and start all over, considering this just a lesson learned :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I have even tried deleting controls and adding new ones. The new ones do not get handlers attached to them.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Is it the case that the answer to my actual question is, "You cannot"? As I poke around in this, it appears that the only document that defines the form also defines the bindings between clicks and developer-code. So there is no way to tell the IDE to use the form to regenerate the bindings and empty code template. No way to export the form without the bindings? Correct? The GUI is hopelessly entwined with the implementation code it binds to. Now THERE is a lesson for someone at Microsoft. Separate the interface from the application. Way too late though. I hope I am wrong.